# Hierarchy for developing several unrelated util packages

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, package

I developed a Java library and the package is called `com.rachum.amir.util.permutation`. I also have a github repo called [Permutations](https://github.com/Nurdok/Permutations), and an Eclipse project. Now I want to add some more stuff to my library, e.g., I want to develop a `com.rachum.amir.util.range` package.  My question is how to arrange the repositories/directory structure. Should I create a new Eclipse `util` project (or actually rename the current Permutation one), and create new projects within 'util`'s directories, or should I create a different, unrelated projects with just shared package names? Is it accustomed to create different git repositories for each sub-package or just one big one, or both?

**Edit**: Another conundrum is how to name the big package. `util` seems to be too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should have one repository for each element that will be released.

So, if your `permutation` package will be released independently from `range`, then have `range` be it's own repository. On the flip-side, if they will always be released together, then you should probably have a single `util` repository and have them both in there.